# Really having trouble with Bootstrap 4 (navbar and flex alignment)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do something exactly like this: 
[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6tu9.png)

I was using the grid system in my old navbar but that wasn't working out in the end the grid system isn't even recommended to be used in the navbar anyway, so I ditched that and decided to start from scratch.

So I tried to use the flexbox but I'm extremely confused, as in the bootstrap documentation there is a ton of options to use and I don't know where to start looking. My biggest problem is the search bar, in how to make it a bit offset to the left and not 100% centered.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="mainNav">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="LogoTeste.png" width="32" height="32" alt="OfertaDB" loading="lazy">
    </a>

<div class="justify-content-end">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginmodal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Cadastre-se
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginmodal"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Login
    </button>    
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: And if we are to expand the width of the page, which way do you want the search bar t go? Left? Right? Because you were not very clear on that. Do the search bar stay the same size? What exactly is "a little offset to the left"?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-wrapper
{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background-color:"#0af";
  justify-content:"space-evenly";
  align-items:"center";
}
.navbar-title
{
  width:15%;
  padding-left:20px;
}
.navbar-search
{
  width:60%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:"center";
  align-items:"center";
}
.navbar-search input
{
  width:100%;
}
.navbar-links
{
  width:25%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:"space-evenly";
  align-items:"center";
}
.navbar-links a
{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-wrapper">

  <div class="navbar-title">
    <h3>Logo</h3>
  </div>
  
  <div class="navbar-search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```